# differences between the workbox-webpack-plugin vs offline-plugin?

Tags: webpack, progressive-web-apps, workbox-webpack-plugin

I want to build my first PWA with webpack 4.
What is the differences between the workbox-webpack-plugin vs offline-plugin?

Comment: meanwhile i found this post https://spectrum.chat/thread/1955e8fd-5c44-4e0a-acd9-8046e53739e2 and i will go now with the offline-plugin for my first try!

Comment: hi! i'm interesed in how its go, i have the same question about workbox vs offline plugin! any thoughts will be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: This might be very helpful: https://www.libtrends.info/npm-compare/offline-plugin-vs-sw-precache-vs-sw-precache-webpack-plugin-vs-workbox-sw-vs-workbox-webpack-plugin